# Run move_base.launch error:[move_base-4] process has died [pid 3825, exit code -11......

Tags: navigation, ros

I got a problem when i run move_base.launch to realize Navigation. The error info in terminal is:

```
[move_base-4] process has died [pid 3825, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/youjian/.ros/log/b66363a2-96cf-11e6-9e46-e4f89cf5c788/move_base-4.log].
log file: /home/youjian/.ros/log/b66363a2-96cf-11e6-9e46-e4f89cf5c788/move_base-4*.log
```

i didnt find move_base-4.log, however i find the error info in `master.log`, the error info is:

```
[rosmaster.threadpool][**ERROR**] 2016-10-20 22:16:04,075: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/threadpool.py", line 218, in run
    result = cmd(*args)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 208, in publisher_update_task
    xmlrpcapi(api).publisherUpdate('/master', topic, pub_uris)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1233, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1587, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1273, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1301, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1448, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 778, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
**error**: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

actually, i managed to run move_base.launch before, but the robot was navigated weirdly, so i want to make the move_base node print the cmd_vel info. Since i cant find move_base.cpp in /opt/ros/indigo, i copied the move_base package from Github and modified the package, then catkin_make it in catkin_ws. However, i didnt make it. So i deleted all files related to move_base in catkin_ws, the result is i couldnt run move_base.launch any more and constantly report the error above.

i have tried reinstall ros-indigo-move-base, but it didnt work. Could anyone give me some help or suggestions? Do i need to reinstall the ROS?>...<

thanks in advance!